# Correct way to pass a click handler from Container, which doesn't modify the state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using React and Redux.

I have a banner component where banners are shown in a carousel.

I have `BannerContainer.js` which is connected to redux and `Banner.js` which is component.

On click of a carousel, I need to do 2 things

1. Redirect user to another url'
2. Fire a GTM event

None of the above actions modify the state. Should I pass an onClick handler via mapDispatchToProps from my container?

What should be the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to dispatch any action, I don't think you need to pass the function in mapDispatchToProps. A local function inside BannerContainer should be enough for you requirements. BTW, what is GTM event? I don't know the abbr.

Comment: Google Tag Manager (GTM), we fire events for tracking in that.

Comment: So this local function, should I pass it as a prop to the component? like ```<Banners onBannerClick={this.localFunction}/>``` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would still pass that in connect, because that's business logic that shouldn't be hidden down your component tree. Otherwise if you need to change the GTM stuff or change routes you will have to find the component.

Create a thunk action creator that performs your side-effects and map it using `mapDispatchToProps`. If your component is not a top-level Route component, you can use `withRouter` to get access to the routing context. You can even compose both decorators or enhancers into own in your container:

```
import { connect, compose } from 'redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import YourComponent from '../components/YourComponent'

// your dispatch
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onBannerClick(e){
       //do your GTM stuff
       //redirect the user!
       ownProps.history.push('/gohere')
    }
  }
}

// combine your enhancers, order is significant if you want
// to have withRouter() props in your connect methods
const enhance = compose(
   withRouter(),
   connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)

export default enhance(YourComponent)
```